# Time-locking and hash-locking in Corda

Tags: bitcoin, corda

Comparing Bitcoin and Corda, can the concepts of time-locking and hash-locking be implemented in Corda?

Multisig, time-lock and hash-lock contracts are explained here (Building Block #3, #4 and #5): https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/understanding-the-lightning-network-part-building-a-bidirectional-payment-channel-1464710791/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sign a Corda tx with a half-open time window on the transaction. This is equivalent to a Bitcoin timelock (tx only valid after a certain timestamp as decided by the notaries clocks).

You can make a "hash lock" by encumbering a cash state with a state containing the hash, in which the verify function ensures the encumbrance can only be removed if the hash pre-image is supplied in a command. However there are no use cases for hash locks that I am aware of.

Corda does not need an equivalent of Bitcoin payment channels for two reasons:

1) We don't use PoW so our consensus mechanisms (notaries) will typically always be fast enough for realistic use cases.

2) It's not a consumer platform, at least not at the moment, so the primary use case for payment channels (micropayments) is irrelevant. Companies do not typically make micropayments to each other and they do not typically trade with anonymous counterparties, which is the main area in which payment channels are useful.

I don't know the background to this query but Corda does not need anything like the Lightning Network. In fact Bitcoin doesn't either.

I can answer this question somewhat authoritatively because I actually made the first proposals for the Bitcoin micropayment channel protocol back in 2011. See Example 7 in this page and its history:

https://en.bitcoin.it/w/index.php?title=Contract&oldid=21404

There's an implementation in the old Bitcoin library I wrote, and I made an app that used it to do micropayments for file downloads:

https://github.com/mikehearn/PayFile

Comment: Be aware, that if you will encumber Cash.State states your other Cash related functionality on the same vault will most likely stop working, as cash selection algorithm does not take into account encumbrance. Also simple writing and registration of cash selection algorithm won't be possible, as current Cash schema implementation does not have link or mark of it being encumbered. I suggest to opt for other solution rather than using Corda's Cash.State and encumbrance togeather